# An internal server error has occurred↵Error only for a user

Tags: user, gack

I am getting 'An internal server error has occurred↵Error ID: 1771101214-172866 (-913457707)' when i login as a particular user and profile. But when I login as a different user with different profile everything works fine. If the component is working for a user but not for a another do anyone face this issue. I checked the same component as admin everything is working fine. Do anyone know how to solve the issue.

Apex code

```
public class cc_caseHandlingInstruction {
@auraenabled
public static knowledgeArticleData fetchKnowledgeWithCaseHandlingInstructions(string category){
    knowledgeArticleData data = new knowledgeArticleData();
    data.status = 'ERROR';
    data.articleDetails = null;
    list<user> userDataList = [SELECT Id,CC_CaseRole__c FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()]; 
    string serviceLevel = '';
    for(User u:userDataList){
        serviceLevel = u.CC_CaseRole__c ; 
    }
    system.debug(serviceLevel);
    string serviceLevelApiName = cc_caseHandlingInstruction.fetchCategoryApiName('Service_Level' , serviceLevel);
    if(!(serviceLevelApiName == 'ERROR' || serviceLevel == '')){
        try{
            Id knowledgeCaseHandlingRecordTypeId ;
            for (RecordType rc : [Select Id From RecordType where sobjecttype = 'Knowledge__kav' AND name = 'Case_Handling_Instruction' LIMIT 1]) {
                knowledgeCaseHandlingRecordTypeId =  rc.Id;
            }
            
            string query = 'SELECT id, Title, Category_Information_CaseHandlingInstr19__c,Category_Information_CategoryId__c FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE Category_Information_CategoryId__c =:';
            query   += 'category AND recordtypeid =: knowledgeCaseHandlingRecordTypeId   WITH DATA CATEGORY  Service_Level__c AT '+ serviceLevelApiName +'__c  LIMIT 1' ;
            
            
            List<Knowledge__kav> knowledgeArticleList = Database.query(query);
            
            if(knowledgeArticleList.size()>0){
                for(Knowledge__kav kav : knowledgeArticleList){
                    data.status = 'SUCCESS';  
                    data.articleDetails = kav;
                }
            }else{
                data.status = 'ERROR';  
                data.articleDetails = null;  
                data.errorMessage = 'No Articles Found';
            }
        }Catch(exception e){
            data.errorMessage = e.getMessage();
        }
    }else{
        if(serviceLevel == ''||serviceLevel == 'none'||serviceLevel == null){
            data.errorMessage = 'User Case Role Not Populated';
        }else if(serviceLevelApiName == ''){
            data.errorMessage = 'User Case Role Configuration ERROR';
        }          
    }

    return data;
}

public static string fetchCategoryApiName(string categoryGroupName ,string CategoryLabel){
    try{
        List<String> objType = new List<String>();
        List<DescribeDataCategoryGroupStructureResult> describeCategoryStructureResult;
        objType.add('KnowledgeArticleVersion');
        
        
        List<DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair> pairsList = new List<DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair>();
        DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair pair = new DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair();
        pair.setSobject('KnowledgeArticleVersion');
        pair.setDataCategoryGroupName(categoryGroupName);
        pairsList.add(pair);
        
        describeCategoryStructureResult = Schema.describeDataCategoryGroupStructures(pairsList, false);
        
        List<DataCategory> allCategories;
        
        for(DescribeDataCategoryGroupStructureResult singleResult : describeCategoryStructureResult){
            
            DataCategory [] toplevelCategories = singleResult.getTopCategories();
            allCategories = getAllCategories(toplevelCategories);
            
            
        }
        for(DataCategory category : allCategories) {
            if(category.getLabel() == CategoryLabel){
                return category.getName();
                
            }
        }
        return 'ERROR';
    }catch(exception e){
        return 'ERROR';   
    }
}


private static DataCategory[] getAllCategories(DataCategory [] categories){
    if(categories.isEmpty()){
        return new DataCategory[]{};
            } else {
                DataCategory [] categoriesClone = categories.clone();
                DataCategory category = categoriesClone[0];
                DataCategory[] allCategories = new DataCategory[]{category};
                categoriesClone.remove(0);
                categoriesClone.addAll(category.getChildCategories());
                allCategories.addAll(getAllCategories(categoriesClone));
                return allCategories;
            }
}

public class knowledgeArticleData {
    @AuraEnabled public string status ;
    @AuraEnabled public string errorMessage; 
    @AuraEnabled public Knowledge__kav articleDetails;
}
}
```

LWC JS

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import apexFetchKnowledgeWithCaseHandlingInstructions from 
'@salesforce/apex/cc_caseHandlingInstruction.fetchKnowledgeWithCaseHandlingInstructions';
import {__isEmpty} from 'c/cc_lwcUtility';
import caseHandlingInstructionsHeader from '@salesforce/label/c.CC_Case_Handling_Instructions';
import showCaseHandlingInstructions from '@salesforce/label/c.CC_Show_Case_Handling_Instructions';

export default class Cc_lwcCaseHandlingInstructions extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

Label = {
        caseHandlingInstructionsHeader,
        showCaseHandlingInstructions
        };
@api recordId;
caseCatergory = '';
result = '';
showCaseHandlingInstructions = false;

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ['Case.Category__c' ] })
getCaseData({ error, data }) {
    if (error) {
        let message = 'Unknown error';
        if (Array.isArray(error.body)) {
            message = error.body.map(e => e.message).join(', ');
        } else if (typeof error.body.message === 'string') {
            message = error.body.message;
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('Error', message);
    } else if (!__isEmpty(data)) {
        this.caseCatergory = data.fields.Category__c.value
        this.getCaseHandlingInstructions();

    } 
}

getCaseHandlingInstructions(){
    console.log('this.caseCatergory ', this.caseCatergory);
    apexFetchKnowledgeWithCaseHandlingInstructions({ category: this.caseCatergory})
        .then(result => {
            if(result.status === 'SUCCESS'){
                this.result = result.articleDetails;
                this.showCaseHandlingInstructions = true;
            }else{
                console.log('ERROR', result.errorMessage);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Server Call Error', error);
        });
}

navigateToObjectHome() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.result.Id,
            objectApiName: 'Knowledge__kav',
            actionName: 'view'
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Which profile are you logging in as? anything you can see that would prevent them from accessing knowledge? I'm pretty sure knowledge isn't available to everyone...

Comment: The profiles which I am using is custom. But the knowledge available is true for the user and in profile also have access to knowledge and the apex class also have access in profile